# Zend MVC project togheter node.js for improve javascript performace

Tags: zend-framework, node.js, v8

i'm working with Zend mvc project with ZendServer.
now i read of node.js that is build on V8 javascript engine with super fast performance to compile javascript code.

is there a way to use node.js for compile the javascript code into my view's mvc projext?,
for example is possible compile javascript in server-side with node but continue to use my zend server to run php as now without distorting my project code?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node doesn't really compile Javascript.  Node is an evented IO system built on top of V8 and works as a full-stack replacement.

You can make them work together, in various ways and depending on your architecture.  For example, it is possible to use Node as a front-line web server and reverse proxy certain requests to your Zend/PHP server.  I had set up this method as a proof-of-concept, because I wanted to use websockets+node along with a PHP site.

In reading your question, I have to assume that you will not want to go down this path.

Comment: I search if there is a way to improve speed of my javascript code into zend mvc project!i'm new of this thing.. do you think that make them work togheter can i improve the speed?

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney What kind of speed issues are you having?  I assume you currently do not have any server-side javascript, so I don't see how Node could help.  If you were to do a significant re-write of your application, then Node could provide some benefits.

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney in short, No, just putting the two together will not improve speed.